# What do the parameters skewX and skewY mean in the transform specified by Flash's motion XML?

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry, transformation, coordinate-systems

Flash has the ability to export animations into a format they call motion XML. Its specification is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/motionXSD.html)

I am trying to write a python renderer for these animations using pyglet. I understand everything, except the "skewX" and "skewY" properties. The spec describes "skewX" as "The angle (in degrees) of shearing along the horizontal axis. If the skewX and skewY values are equal, they are replaced by the rotation attribute."

Now, when I looked up shearing, it turns out that it doesn't describe what they mean by it. Equal shearing along X and Y does not result in rotation around Z. Furthermore, I've noticed that they sometimes represent mirroring around Y as a skewY of 180 degrees. Shearing does not do this. [This page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ShearingTransform.html) is particularly helpful when it comes to shearing. It says the shear matrix for a given angle is:[image]

So my question is this, what is the transform that they actually mean by this? What transform skews along X or Y, for values greater than 180 degrees causes mirroring and when used equally on X and Y results in rotation?

Any clues would be helpful. Also, if this question belongs somewhere else(not on math.stackexchange please let me know and I'll move it)

Comment: You should be asking in some forum dedicated to flash... There you will find (hopefully!) information about what the drafters of the spec meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue / question.  I was able to find the matrices Adobe was generating by making a short script and looking at the `DisplayObject.transform.matrix` property of a sample shape that I applied different values for shear to through the Transformation tool.

After trying this for a few values, I am convinced the transform Adobe is applying for shear is splitting X/Y of a rotation transform :

\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\text{shearY}) & \sin(\text{shearY}) & 0\\ 
-\sin(\text{shearX}) & \cos(\text{shearX}) & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

If `shearX == shearY` this is equal to a rotation transform, and at `shearX == 180` or `shearY == 180` (degrees) it creates -1 scale transforms on Y or X respectively.

Comment: Wow, I had despaired of finding an answer to this one. I'm trying this out and if it turns out this is the correct answer I'll upvote and accept within 24hrs :)

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks! :)